How can PDA seeds be an array, when they're calculated at runtime?
My understanding is that in Rust, Arrays are used for items whose size is known at compile time, and Vectors are used for items whose size is unknown at compile time.
But the way we set seeds for PDAs in Anchor is as an array of arrays of bytes:
seeds = [b"somestring", somesigner.key().as_ref(), someu64.id.to_le_bytes().as_ref()],

This doesn't quite seem to make sense - every time this instruction handler is called, the account constraints must be checked. Eg, maybe this time the somesigner has changed, or the user is using a different value fro someu64.
How can PDA seeds be an array, when they're calculated at runtime?


Answering myself in case it helps others...

The amount of seeds (the outer item) is a constantly sized array
Eg for
seeds = [b"somestring", somesigner.key().as_ref(), someu64.id.to_le_bytes().as_ref()],

We always have 3 seeds (somestring, somesigner, and someu64), this is known at compile time.
The inner item is a slice, not an array
My understanding of what the inner [u8] is was incorrect - it's a slice, not an array

In Rust, the type [u8] represents a slice rather than an array. While arrays in Rust are fixed in size, slices are views into arrays or vectors and can vary in length.


In my opinion, PDA seeds can be an array because the structure (number and size of slices) is fixed at compile time, while the values in the slices are computed dynamically at runtime.

Yes agreed. That's very similar to the existing answer though, with a little less detail.

PDA seeds can be an array because the array is created dynamically at runtime, but still passed as a fixed reference to find_program_address, which computes the deterministic PDA.

I don't think this is correct. I think the outer array is created at compile time (that's why it has a size) and the inner array is actually not an array, but rather a slice of bytes which may have a dynamic length. See my own answer. If I'm wrong though let me know!
